# How to maintain unknown/wildcard queryParams through a transition?

Tags: ember.js

I have a route (`route-a`) that transitions to another route (`route-b`) and I am trying to find a way for the destination URL to maintain the *all* query parameters, even if `route-b` does not know about them in advance.

For example, if a user visits `https://example.com/route-a/?var1=x&var2=y`, and the transition to `route-b` happens like this:

```js
afterModel(model, transition) {
  this.transitionTo('route-b', model, {queryParams: transition.to.queryParams}) // transition route-a to route-b
}
```

...the ultimate URL will be `https://example.com/route-b/` — *without* the query params.

Now, I realize the "Ember way" is to define the queryParams on `route-b`'s controller in advance, but in this particular use-case, *I do not know the queryParams in advance*. Route B consumes any and all query params provided to it, which means they would be impossible to enumerate in advance.

How can I transition to a new route without dropping query parameters that are not specifically enumerated on the destination route's controller?

Is there a way to handle unknown queryParams, or is there the notion of a wildcard for queryParams (similar to `*path` routes)?

Comment: Interesting question. What is `route-b` supposed to do with these query params if it does not even know their names?

Comment: Would it be a workaround to URL-encode all query params and pass them to _one_ query param / controller variable in `route-b`, where they are parsed/split again?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I'm not marking this as the answer, because as jelhan notes below, using a computed property for this key is explicitly identified as a no-no in the docs. But it worked for our use-case, and it might for others, though I'm guessing it may break down if you have additional `queryParams` in other routes that might conflict when Ember attempts to combine them.

**Previous answer:**

My solution here ended up using Ember's `computed` method to auto-generate the Array of query params by parsing the URL.

```js
  queryParams: computed("router.location", function () {
    let qp = this.get("router.location").getURL().split("?")[1];
    if (qp) {
      let qpAsObj = JSON.parse(
        '{"' +
          decodeURI(qp)
            .replace(/"/g, '\\"')
            .replace(/&/g, '","')
            .replace(/=/g, '":"') +
          '"}'
      );
      return Object.keys(qpAsObj)
    }
  })
```

If you don't want to subsequently maintain those query params on the page/model the next time a user re-visits that page ("[sticky query params](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/query-params/#toc_sticky-query-param-values)"), you will also need to remove the queryParams on the route:

```js
  resetController(controller) {
    // unset all queryParams when leaving the route
    controller.queryParams.forEach(v => {
      controller.set(v, null)
    })
  }
```

This solution is... not ideal, but it works and we have tests written to ensure that we will catch any errors if it breaks going forward.

Comment: Ember [explicitly documents](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/) that `queryParams` must not be a dynamically generated property. You are leaving the happy path for sure. I would reconsider this solution. Or at least make sure to have very good test coverage.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ability to have unknown query parameters able to be passed through a transition is a hard requirement, and this is the only thing I've found that "works" (and I've tried almost everything). I was legitimately shocked that Ember doesn't support this, but throw it on the pile of Ember edge-cases that complicate my life